# Authenticate websocket with keycloak through openresty

Tags: nginx, websocket, keycloak, openresty, lua-resty-openidc

Currently I have a working solution with following components:

- Webserver with custom application
- Openresty with lua
- Keycloak

This allows me to authenticate using keycloak.
Because my webserver also exposes a websocket host, I would like to authenticate these websockets as well. Does anyone have an example (both the nginx file as the lua file) available to authenticate websocket connections using openresty? I've had a look at https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-websocket but can't seem to find where to plugin in the authentication part.
An example client application to test this would be great as well!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've figured it out myself. Posting my solution here to help others achieving the same.
I have following code snippets:

### Openresty configuration

only for websocket, should be place inside the server section:

```
set $resty_user 'not_authenticated_resty_user';
location /ws {
      access_by_lua_file         /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/lua_access.lua;
      proxy_pass                    http://<backend-websocket-host>/ws;
      proxy_http_version            1.1;
      proxy_set_header              Host                $http_host;
      proxy_set_header              X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header              X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

      proxy_set_header              Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header              Connection          "upgrade";
      proxy_set_header              X-Forwared-User     $resty_user;
      proxy_read_timeout            1d;
      proxy_send_timeout            1d;
    }
```

### lua_acces.lua

```
local opts = {
    redirect_uri = "/*",
    discovery = "http://<keycloak-url>/auth/realms/realm/.well-known/openid-configuration",
    client_id = "<client-id>",
    client_secret = "<client-secret>",
    redirect_uri_scheme = "https",
    logout_path = "/logout",
    redirect_after_logout_uri = "http://<keycloak-url>/auth/realms/realm/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2google.com",
    redirect_after_logout_with_id_token_hint = false,
    session_contents = {id_token=true},
    ssl_verify=no
  }

  -- call introspect for OAuth 2.0 Bearer Access Token validation
  local res, err = require("resty.openidc").bearer_jwt_verify(opts)
  if err or not res then
    print("Token authentication not succeeded")
    if err then
      print("jwt_verify error message:")
      print(err)
    end
    if res then
      print("jwt_verify response:")
      tprint(res)
    end
    res, err = require("resty.openidc").authenticate(opts)
    if err then
      ngx.status = 403
      ngx.say(err)
      ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_FORBIDDEN)
    end
  end

if res.id_token and res.id_token.preferred_username then
    ngx.var.resty_user = res.id_token.preferred_username
  else
    ngx.var.resty_user = res.preferred_username
  end
```

This allows websocket connections only when they have a valid token retrieved from the keycloak service.
At the end, the resty user is filled in to pass on the authenticated user to the backend application.

### Example Java client application

#### Get keycloak token

```
package test;

import org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak;
import org.keycloak.representations.AccessTokenResponse;

public class KeycloakConnection {
    private Keycloak _keycloak;

    public KeycloakConnection(final String host, String username, String password, String clientSecret, String realm, String clientId) {

        _keycloak = Keycloak.getInstance(
                "http://" + host + "/auth",
                realm,
                username,
                password,
                clientId,
                clientSecret);
    }

    public String GetAccessToken()
    {
        final AccessTokenResponse accessToken = _keycloak.tokenManager().getAccessToken();
        return accessToken.getToken();
    }
}
```

#### Websocket

This snippet only contains the function I call to setup the websocket connection. You still have to instantiate the _keycloakConnection object and in my case I have a general _session field to keep reuse the session each time I need it.

```
private Session GetWebsocketSession(String host)
    {
        URI uri = URI.create("wss://" + host);
        ClientUpgradeRequest request = new ClientUpgradeRequest();
        request.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + _keycloakConnection.GetAccessToken());
        _client = new WebSocketClient();
        try {
                _client.start();
                // The socket that receives events
                WebsocketEventHandler socketEventHandler = new WebsocketEventHandler(this::NewLiveMessageReceivedInternal);
                // Attempt Connect
                Future<Session> fut = _client.connect(socketEventHandler, uri, request);
                // Wait for Connect
                _session = fut.get();

                return _session;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            _logger.error("Error during websocket session creation", t);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

#### WebsocketEventHandler

A consumer is injected in this class to consume the messages in another class

```
package test;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.WebSocketAdapter;

import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class WebsocketEventHandler extends WebSocketAdapter
{
    private final Logger _logger;
    private Consumer<String> _onMessage;

    public WebsocketEventHandler(Consumer<String> onMessage) {
        _onMessage = onMessage;
        _logger = Logger.getLogger(WebsocketEventHandler.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWebSocketConnect(Session sess)
    {
        super.onWebSocketConnect(sess);
        _logger.info("Socket Connected: " + sess);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWebSocketText(String message)
    {
        super.onWebSocketText(message);
        _logger.info("Received TEXT message: " + message);
        _onMessage.accept(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWebSocketClose(int statusCode, String reason)
    {
        super.onWebSocketClose(statusCode,reason);
        _logger.info("Socket Closed: [" + statusCode + "] " + reason);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWebSocketError(Throwable cause)
    {
        super.onWebSocketError(cause);
        _logger.error("Websocket error", cause);
    }
}
```

#### Sending messages

When the _session is created you can use following line to send data:

```
_session.getRemote().sendString("Hello world");
```

These snippets are all a small part of my whole solution. I might have missed something. If somebody has a question or this is not working in your case, please reach out and I'll provide more information.